# PHP display div with select option

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I have two tables 
material :

```
 - id :int,
 - name : varchar(255),
 - providers_id : int (foreign key)
```

And table providers :

```
 - id_provider: int,
 - code_providers : varchar(200)
```

I have some data in the table providers :

> ```
> 1,provider1
> 2,provider2
> 3,provider3
> ```

And i have page  addMaterial.php :

```
<div class="form-group" id="TextBoxDiv1">
    <label>Providers</label>
        <select class="form-control">
             <option value='-1'>Choose provider</option>
                <?php       
                    $stmt2 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM providers");
                              $stmt2->execute();
                                while($row2 = $stmt2->fetch()){
                                  echo "<option value='".$row2["id_provider"]."'>".$row2["code_provider"]."</option>";
                                    }
                ?>

          </select>  

</div> 

<div>add</div>
<div>update</div>
<div>delete</div>
```

- **I would like to display div add when i choose provider 1**
- **I would like to display div update when i choose provider 2**
- **I would like to display div update when i choose provider 3**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" id="chooseProvider">
 ...

<div id="add">add</div>
<div id="update">update</div>
<div>delete</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#chooseProvider").change(function(){
    if($(this).val()=="1"){
       $("#add").show();
       $("#update").hide();
    } 
    else if($(this).val()=="2" || $(this).val()=="3"){
       $("#update").show();
       $("#add").hide();
    }
});
```